# Problem with R.JAVA and Resources not Find

Tags: android-layout

Unfortunately I have often (that's the third time!) working with Android project in Eclipse (directly with Debug) and usually after I update the graphic layout of an XML file, to appear in my classes a series problems, such as: 
R.drawable.myIcon "can not be resolved myIcon or not is a field" and so for all graphic objects / resources in the XML file layout graph to which I had previously given an ID. 
Every time I have to return to the last saved version of the project :(

I searched in internet possible causes and solutions ..... the possible solutions I have tried everything .....

1. Clean & Rebuild repeated and continuous ....
2. Delete file R.JAVA and rebuild automatically (Automatically Build or Build ALL )
3. Android Tools-fix project properties
4. re-run "import android.R" in my class
5. "comment" all the error code to recompile the Eclipse    project and
   get a clean design and error
6. Re-create a new    workspace and import the project
7. I updated the Android SDK, which    was still very recent.  (SDK
   from revision 11 to revision 12).I    updated: - Eclipse
   Platform/Platform SDK/Eclipse SDK
8. I tried    F5-Refresh in Eclipse

   9).I tried ANT (apache-ant-1.8.2-bin.zip) to    Automate Building
   Android Applications  (Build.XML has successfully    created both
   from DOS and from Eclipse)

but in the end I can never fix the bug where  **only**  in my class all the specific resources of the file / class JAVA R. are not seen.

Report From: 
R. JAVA-file that the resources referred to by my class there are in fact! 
-In Window "Error Log" is the error: "Invalid preference page path: XML Syntax" but with no reference to any file 
-Graphical layout of the XML file there is no error message 
Someone managed to solve this problem in Android ?

Answer (score 3):

If all those things tried by user840370 doesn't solve the error

> "Invalid preference page path: XML Syntax"

Just import `com.your.packagename.R` class and it will work !

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this problem.

It turned out to be due to duplicate id's in one of my layout files.

Answer (score 2):

Names of files in resources can't contain capital letters, so `myIcon` is wrong name. File names must contain only [a-z0-9_.] (small letters, numbers, '_' and '.').

Answer (score 0):

And just to say it, my answer to this same question was correcting my Android project's targetSdkVersion in the Manifest.xml to match the project properties. =X

Those XML problems.. they'll getcha! :P